# Comunicação Serial Com PHP e Arduino

Tags: php, arduino, serial

Já tenho um código na IDE do arduino, no qual quando passado a letra 'l', um led será acesso, entretanto, não consigo de forma alguma acessar essa porta serial com PHP, estou utilizando Fedora 22, Arduino Uno, os códigos estão abaixo:

**Código Arduino, porta utilizada /dev/ttyACM0**

```
void setup() {
   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
   char caracter = Serial.read();
   if(caracter == 'l'){
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
   }
}
```

**Código PHP, pssando o caracter 'l'**

```
<?php
   $porta = fopen("/dev/ttyACM0", "w");
   fwrite($porta, 'l');
   fclose($porta);
?>
```

Dei um var_dump na variável $porta e ela me retornou false, agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Comment: Provavelmente o executavel do PHP ou apache não tem permissões de escrever em `/dev/ttyACM0`, me parece o mais provável. Tambem não sei se seu kernel possui os drivers nescessários. Alguns arduinos "piratas" tem drivers especificos

Comment: Certeza que é permissão tive esse mesmo problema no linux, da um chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0 que vai funcionar. !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

então eu resolvi o problema, não consegui de forma alguma fazer a leitura e escrita dos dados da porta serial através do PHP, porém depois de muitas pesquisas, consegui fazer a leitura e escrita dos dados pelo prompt de comando (estou usando Windows) e com o php consegui fazer a leitura dos dados do prompt. A lógica é a seguinte, o PHP manda executar um script powershell com a função 'exec', este script manda um caractere para a porta serial e o arduino com este dado faz alguma coisa. Para mais informações, segue o tutorial que me ajudou bastante na parte dos scripts em powershell: [PowerShell Scripts Serial Port](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/command-line-windows-mac-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, eu sou muito ajudado por tutoriais e fórum, sou hobista então tudo que faço é com muito esforço e pesquisa, e fiquei uns 3 meses buscando essa solução, basicamente o código no Windows muda um pouco:

```
$fj = fopen("COM2", "w"); 
//o "w" muda de acordo com o que vc quer fazer, pode ser "w" "a" "r" no site do manual php tem mais informacoes.
$escreve = fwrite($fj, '1');
fclose($fj);
```

Funciona na porta COM2 e você precisará mudar as configurações na porta serial dentro de "Gerenciador de dispositivos", "portas ", "USB porta serial(COM2)", "Definições da porta" e "avançadas", "mudei o temporizador e marquei todas as opções do lado esquerdo, mas há o risco de queimar a entrada serial do Arduíno, o que provavelmente aconteceu comigo depois de algumas vezes que acendi um led.

Obs. você precisa fazer a mudança de configuração depois que enviar o código Arduíno, senão não funciona. Tentativas e erros. Não instala um tal de Firmata, só zimbra o Arduíno e não tem como tirar mais.

Answer (score 0):

Use o PHP-Serial
[link aqui](https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial)

exemplo :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include "php_serial.class.php";

$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyAMA0");
$serial->confBaudRate(115200);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->deviceOpen();
$serial->sendMessage("L");

$serial->deviceClose();

echo "comando enviado! \n\r";
```

Comment: Então, já tentei implementar com este script, mas também sem sucesso, o mesmo erro ocorre, acesso negado a porta. Obs: realizei testes em três máquinas diferentes, com Fedora 22, com Ubuntu 14.04 em com Windows 10, todos em máquinas distintas e sem nenhum sucesso.

Comment: nesse site tem o exemplo do php Serial em uso no linux, no final tem o comando pra porta serial funcionar.
http://www.embarcados.com.br/sistema-web-com-raspberry-pi-e-arduino/

Comment: Vou dar uma conferida assim que possível e estarei retornando o resultado.

Answer (score -1):

Já tentou via socket? Segue um exemplo básico:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($sock,"187.15.6.131", 8081); // Ip e porta que você configurou no seu arduino
socket_write($sock,'l', 1);
socket_close($sock);
```

Para mais funções e melhor entendimento consulte o [manual do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.socket-create.php).

Espero que ajude, abraços.